# Cannot edit database table when starting db docker container

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker

I spin up a SQL Server database instance inside docker container with following command:

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=login*' -e 'MSSQL_PID=Express' -p 1445:1443 
--name=myDB microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
```

Everything works well. After restarting machine I started same container with

```
docker start myDB
```

Now when I try to edit a database table using SQL Server Management Studio, I get:

[image]

Comment: DanGuzman, that's true. Post is an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be an error with the SSMS client. First, try restarting SSMS. If the problem persists, it could be the SSMS installation is corrupt, in which case an SSMS reinstall might be the solution.